# Sending Push notification to android Using PHP :curl failed

Tags: php, android, curl

I am trying to send push notification some android devices using the registration ids which is stored in database table.

Here is my code

```
  //message and title for push notification
  $msg=$_POST['message'];
  $title=$_POST['title'];
  $result=$connect->prepare("SELECT `push_id` FROM `user_devices`");
  $result->execute();
  //get registration id's
  $ids=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
  $key="XXXXX";
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
  $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  =>$ids,
                'data'              => array( "message" =>$msg,"title"=>$title,"soundname"=>"beep.wav" ),
                );
  $headers = array(
                    'Authorization: key=' . $key,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  if($res === false)
     echo 'Curl failed ' .curl_error();
  }
```

I am getting `curl Failed` error message but didn't see anything  from curl_error().

**UPDATE**

I am running this script from windows server which is hosted in azure cloud service.
Now i am run this from linux based server its works fine,but it didnt work in windows server.

Comment: Have to enabled curl ?

Comment: print $res and tell me what you will get in it.

Comment: Yes curl is enabled.

Comment: @jilesh getting empty

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting error due to SSL (in your url https) issue. You have to configure your curl to handle secured request. You can find a hints from here: [Configuring cURL for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467648/configuring-curl-for-ssl)

You are not getting the error msg because you need to print it like below:

```
echo 'Curl failed ' .curl_error($ch); // you are missing $ch here
```

Alternately you can run your curl with verbose enabled to see the things happening with your curl request!

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem of My SSL Certificate.

Solved using one line code
 `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` is placed in after curl_init.

**NOTE**

This is a temporary solution.Actual way is generate an SSl certificate.