# How to successfully pull data from Veracode through REST API?

Tags: rest, veracode

I'm trying to pull data from veracode(json or xml). I tried to use curl to connect to the api but i keep getting the error:"Failed to connect to analysiscenter.veracode.com port 443:Timed out".

```
curl --compressed -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/api/5.0/getapplist.do -F "include_user_info=true"
```

According to veracode documentation, to connect to the API, one needs to have  Reviewer or Security Lead role.I have both Reviewer and Submitter role.The curl command should return some data like this:

> > xsi:schemaLocation="https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/applist https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/resource/2.0/applist.xsd" >applist_version="1.2" account_id="123">Code" policy_updated_date="2013-11-11T14:37:34-05:00"/>
> >     create_application_profile="true" create_sandbox="true" >create_new_build="true" assign_app_to_team="true" >assign_app_to_any_team="true" view_sandbox="true" view_results="true" >approve_mitigations="true" submit_static_scan="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a network issue, based on the error that you pasted.  Can you ping the URL?

CURL also needs some configuration to use SSL.  See this answer for some tips:

[Configuring cURL for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467648/configuring-curl-for-ssl)