# PHP post to API (trying with cURL)

Tags: php, curl

If I go directly to the URL with the right params in the URL, I get a success response.

The URL looks like

```
https://api.theService.com/send?client_id=54&token=7545h5h554&format=json
```

In PHP, I tried something like

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$client_id = 54;
$token = '7545h5h554';

$ch = curl_init('https://api.theService.com/send?client_id='.$client_id.'&token='.$token.'&format=json');

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($responseData);
echo "</pre>";
```

However I never get a response with the above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP CURL & HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: For the person who put "This question may already have an answer here:" -- you may want to take it off. The answer was related to something else (see tuga and comments to his answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$client_id = 54;
$token = '7545h5h554';
$url  = "https://api.theService.com/send?client_id=$client_id&token=$token&format=json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); //waits 10 seconds for response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
echo $page;
```

You should also try checking the error messages in `curl_error()`.
http://www.php.net/curl_error

Comment: Thanks for the help -- even with that curl_error in there, the page just keeps loading. As if the request just never gets done.

Comment: After waiting ~2 minutes, I got Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.theService.com:443

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
 did it :)

Comment: You can add this to your answer and I will select you.

Comment: You may have a network issue, I've added `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`to my answer, so curl only waits 10 seconds for a response.

Comment: @DanyP You found your solution, great! I've updated my answer.