# how to include https site using php

Tags: php

I tried to include iframe videos in my php, like this one [Vk Video](http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=250349454&id=169859391&hash=af2327b1f2db9f87&hd=1), so my php file will do the exact job as that video page, but i haven't gone so far, i tried `file_get_contents` but i got Warning with https videos. so is there any way that i can include http and https pages inside my php file?

**note: i am bad at English so sorry ...**

**note: i am beginner in php ...**

Comment: No problem. Can you supply the URL of the video?

Comment: it's in the Question, and here it is [link](https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=250349454&id=169859391&hash=af2327b1f2db9f87&hd=1)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: I don't think file_get_contents would be able to handle https.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but i didn't understand the code you gave me! i am very beginner, where should i put the url in the code? can you explain it for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
);

$ch      = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err     = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

$header['errno']   = $err;
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
echo $content;
}
get_web_page( 'http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=250349454&id=169859391&hash=af2327b1f2db9f87&hd=1' );
```

Comment: I've seen that function on SO before, care to reference where you copied it from?

Comment: It's referenced in the comments above. If I wanted to take credit for this not particularly well-written code I would have just bundled it straight into an answer rather than posting it as a comment, which often get no reward. Didn't think it was worth the duplication. OP is having issues with HTTPS in PHP; Q has been answered several times.

Comment: That's what the flag as duplicate option is for. Referencing your answer would be beneficial as often people don't read comments

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that facility.