# API gives a JSON response, but PHP doesn't treat it as JSON on the HTTP request, only if I copy to a local file

Tags: php, json, api, object

I am using an API that gives a JSON response. If I copy that response into a 'test.txt' file and retrieve data from it - it's fine. However, if I try to `@file_get_contents` directly on the HTTPS url, I get a non-object.

```
function fetchMeasurments($url, $energyCoefficient, $filePrefix) {
    $connectionSettings = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
        array(
            'timeout' => 5
        )
    ));
$jsonData = @file_get_contents($url, false, $connectionSettings);
$obj = json_decode($jsonData);
    if( is_null($obj) ){
        echo 'null'; die();
    }else{
        echo 'not null'; die();
}
```

If I use test.txt - I get 'not null', but if I use the HTTPS url, I get null. Any thoughts?

Here is the JSON response:

```
{"overview":{"lastUpdateTime":"2014-10-27 11:03:15","lifeTimeData":{"energy":2.1047042E7,"revenue":2639.4795},"lastYearData":{"energy":2.105334E7},"lastMonthData":{"energy":1388652.8},"lastDayData":{"energy":749.25397},"currentPower":{"power":817.0}}}
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling it has something to do with the SSL - but not sure why/how

Comment: JSON response is perfect. may be try https with cURL ?

Comment: Wild guess: could be the server gives the JSON with the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of some sort.

Comment: Hi @AncientGeek - can you please give an example? If I put this JSON file on an HTTP it works fine, but on an HTTPS it doesn't

Comment: Hi @Cthulhu - how would i determine this?

Comment: @GuitarMan  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: Don't suppress error message with `@` and you'll likely see what is wrong.

Comment: You can just use CURL as Robert suggested in his answer. But file_get_contents supports SSL just fine. You need to ensure the openssl module is enabled.

Comment: @rjdown - you are right - the openssl module was the problem. Appreciate the input of everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should really consider using CURL instead of file_get_contents(). Curl has support for secure connections and you will not have problems with https.

Morover suppresion of errors is not a good idea.

Here you have tutorial how to make CURL connections with https

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

```
function getData($url)
{ 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Use this function instead of file_get_contents().

Notice this is very basic function without setting headers, error handling and certificate acceptation.