# How to call outside page using ajax/jquery instead of using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to call another page for example `http://www.google.com` to my specific div. I had done using ajax...

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'http://www.google.com',
     success : function (data)
     {
         $('#my-div').html(data);
     }
});
```

But it does not work....Is there any better ways instead of using `<iframe>` ?

Comment: If I call the page inside my system..there is no problem...but in my case, i need to call third party page...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work due to the same-origin policy (if your ajax code is on *www.mysite.com*, you can only send ajax requests to other files on *www.mysite.com*).

Here are 2 common solutions:

1) If you can write server side code, you can ajax your own domain, [scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) www.google.com using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) and return the response.

2) With ajax you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but one condition is that the server (www.google.com in your case) is configured for JSONP responses. Checkout the [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for how to go about JSONP.

Comment: So its means I can not call another page if I'm not using CURL?

Comment: If it's PHP look up http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. For JSONP check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#example-0. But JSONP will only work if the site you are targeting is letting it work.

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP ...Actually i need to call another page of survey,...the page was https and it does not work to use file-get-contents....

Comment: Ok. Check this out for cURL over https http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: I see. This is file_get_contents over https http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https