# PHP Curl: Unable to send extra header

Tags: php, curl

I have the following curl code:

```
$url    = "https://example.com/api/blah/";
$result = remoteRequest ($url, 'POST', $postValues, true, true, array("X-Forwarded-For: $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"));
```

with the main function being:

```
function remoteRequest ($url, $type='POST', $postValues=array(), $json=true, $parseResponse=true, $extraHeaders=array())
{
    $curl = curl_init ($url);

    $postValuesString = '';
    if ($json && $postValues) {
        $postValuesString = json_encode ($postValues);
    }

    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if ($extraHeaders) {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $extraHeaders);
    }

    if ($type == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }

    if ($postValues || $postValuesString) {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValuesString ? $postValuesString : $postValues);
    }

    if ($json) {
        if ($type == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        }
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postValuesString)));
    }

    $rc = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

    return $rc;

}
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but the extra headers (x-forwarded-for) are simply not included in the request header.

I've verified this through some debug code as well as routing the curl request through squid and taking a look at it's log file.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and what I have to do in order to get the x-forwarded-for header added to my request? I've even started wondering whether this could be related to me accessing a https (rather than http) URL but I'm guessing it's probably something else.

For the record, I'm using 5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 on Ubunty 14.04.

Comment: I think problem with https protocol. Referrer this link it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: This's my class based on curl,it supports multi-http(s)-request including get and post,also supports server proxy: ) [iHttp](https://github.com/phpjungle/iHttp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're setting `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` again later in the code

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe the solution is this simple. I've been staring at this for hours and never even considered that this might be the problem. It now works like a charm.