# Using Curl from SSL server to download xml feed?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

When i try this code on some other server it works properly, but when i run it on server where is SSL "installed" i get empty string from *var_dump*.

```
$feedUrl = 'https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/feed?sportid=29&leagueid=1980-1977-1957-1958-1983-2421-2417-2418-2419-1842-1843-2436-2438-2196-2432-2036-2037-1928-1817-2386-2592-2081';
// Set your credentials here, format = clientid:password from your account.
$credentials = base64_encode("password");
// Build the header, the content-type can also be application/json if needed
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/xml';
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials;
// Set up a CURL channel.
$httpChannel = curl_init();
// Prime the channel
curl_setopt($httpChannel, CURLOPT_URL, $feedUrl);
curl_setopt($httpChannel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($httpChannel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($httpChannel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)' );
// Unless you have all the CA certificates installed in your trusted root authority, this should be left as false.
curl_setopt($httpChannel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// This fetches the initial feed result. Next we will fetch the update using the fdTime value and the last URL parameter
$initialFeed = curl_exec($httpChannel);
//var_dump($initialFeed);
```

I already have script **on this ssl server** who downloads csv files from an other url and it works normally, so i think that problem is in my header, but how it works on other servers, same code?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

Basically says to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
```

Or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)

Comment: First won't work.
Second returns me whole page with message that i am blocked.