# Send GET HTTPS request with custom headers PHP

Tags: php, curl, https, get, request

I want to send a HTTPS request in PHP with custom parameters. I tried with curl method :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myurl.com/item/books');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,array('Token: 888888888'));

$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info['request_header']);
```

My problem is that my request (GET) is in HTTPS and I can't send the header parameter Token: 888888.
I have tried with:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Token: 888888888'));
```

And it doesn't work because my request is in HTPPS. I need the proper method to send my HTTPS request with custom headers.
(Many example in Internet are for HTTP request not HTTPS)

Thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https). Pretty straight forward fix, although I don't recommend using the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` instead, if possible, take care of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a curl option for handling HTTPS request that is

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** : FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```