# why Instagram returns blank to CURL request?

Tags: php

i write following code to get html data from url and its working for https site like Facebook but not working for Instagram only.
Instagram returns the blank

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com';
$returned_content = get_data($url);
print_r($returned_content)
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Because you have a syntax error here.

Comment: Apart from the syntax error, you are using `print_r()` to print the output. If you `var_dump()` it, you'll see the actual size of the string but it will still show up as an empty string because the function does not parse HTML output, so it is interpreted by your browser like that. Try using `htmlspecialchars()` (although I'm not sure if that's what you want to achieve)

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars($returned_content)` to see the response without render in the browser. The `www.instagram.com` will return the `<head>` and the `<body>`, however the `<body>` is only javascript, that can not be handle by the curl itself. The JS will not work in your browser because your domain is diferent, so is impossible reach the file and maybe have a CORS.

Answer (score 1):

The Instagram will return only javascript, that can't be render by your browser because it uses dynamic path, so `<script src='/path/file.js'>` will try to get `localhost/path/file.js` instead of `instagram.com/path/file.js` and in this  situation the `localhost/path/file.js` not will exist, so the page will be *blank*.

---

One solution is find a way to give the *full HTML*  instead of the *Javascript*, in this case you can use the "User-Agent" to do this trick. *You might know that JS not handle by the search-engine, so for this situation the Instagram (and many websites) give the page without JS that is supported by the bot.*

**So, add this:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "ABACHOBot");
```

The "ABACHOBot" is one Crawler. [In this page you can found many others alternatives](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Crawler), like a "Baiduspider", "BecomeBot"...

You can use "generic" user-agent too, like "bot", "spider", "crawler" and probably will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this on

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com';
$returned_content = get_data($url);
print_r($returned_content);
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  //Update.................
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'spider');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  //....................................................
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

You should pass
`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`
and other **header** info as above.
For more detail,Please see
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https`