# What is the best approach for (https) php server to (http) php server communications?

Tags: php, server, joomla3.0

We have a centralised CRM that manages tickets from customers, this service is secured with a ssl certificate. To help speed up ticket handling I wrote and tested code that would:

1. Create a ticket from a client
2. Edit the ticket on our CRM
3. Make posts from CRM to client's Joomla site with a AJAX post.

Everything works perfectly on our test server as all services were over http.

Working case:
CRM browser  (http) -> CRM (handle ticket and click save) which in effect is CRM browser  (http)AJAX -> client's Joomla (http) site. *Works*

BUT our production CRM is https which means that I cannot save, as this is:

CRM browser (https) -> CRM (handle ticket and click save) which in effect is CRM browser (https)AJAX -> client's Joomla (http) site. *Does Not Work due to CORS*

I have read many articles and I cannot find a definitive approach to working around this issue.

One idea I've had is to use PHP sockets. The process would be to AJAX https post to our CRM backend and then use socket communication to the http Joomla site.

Should I use PHP socket communication or is there a work around to use AJAX from a https site to a http site?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this answer and it gave me exactly what I needed.

[PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372730/1265302)

However, I'd still like to know if sockets is a good approach.