# PHP: Curl is still not returning the sourcecode

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have now tried a lot of different solutions but non of those curl settings has ever worked... I just want to get the sourcecode of the webpage back...

And yeah, I know there is `file_get_contents()`. But I need and want to use curl instand of `file_get_contents()`. Where is the error? How can I get the content of the webpage with curl?

```
$url = "https://google.de";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
//    "API-Token: " . APITOKEN . "",
//    "API-Secret: " . APISECRET . "",
//));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo "This is the response...:\n" . $response;
```

`$response` is always empty... Even if I save the variable to a text file... Here the picture which proves it!

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5JAq.png)

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Please use `curl_error` and `curl_errno`  to show what errors you got.

Comment: Why do you want to use curl instead of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: What about var_dump($response):

Comment: `var_dump` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)

Answer (score 0):

Please dump `curl_error($curl)`. Then you will get `"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`.

You can simply set the following options to avoid this error:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Warn: the above solution disables SSL verification and is not secure. A secure solution is to set the certification of cURL:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH_TO/cacert.pem");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            If you will check error  then you will show below error

        if(!curl_exec($curl)){
          die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
           }

 Error: "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" - Code: 60

    To solve this issue you can follow this link-

    https://wehavefaces.net/fixing-ssl-certificate-problem-when-performing-https-requests-in-php-e3b2bb5c58f6
```