# curl using in https site to call http api

Tags: php, api, curl

I tried accessing a api using curl and it getting output in non https site, but I update this code in https certify site but not working. I have tried code as like below it is working in non-https site.

```
$url = "http://45.116.113.98:8081/WebAP1/api/SchemeMast/1/40/WEBDTG100-/45/-/Prabakaran/S/-/4-44,pillaiyar%20kovil%20street,ko.thoppu%20vill,nochalu/-/Villupuram/Villupuram/Tamil%20Nadu/India/604201/9787162221/9787162221/0.000/100.00/2017-12-21/C"; 
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg'; 
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

And also tried in this way also,

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

But both are not working in my https site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` only this could be enough for that.. But i tried to access your url, but is not working. Your curl script seems to be good.

Comment: But not working in my https site, same thing working in my http site

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is described here:

```
curl -i https://45.116.113.98:8081
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

and [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://45.116.113.98:8081)

[image]

It means that HTTPS protocol is not supported,

maybe because site not configured to support HTTPS

or you're using wrong port (by default: http -> 80, https -> 443).

Comment: My site name is https://www.srisaravanajewellers.in. I'm calling api http://45.116.113.98:8081

Comment: In this case, it means that api 45.116.113.98:8081 doesn't support https protocol! You have to communicate with support team and ask them to configure https.

Comment: But please don't use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` you may end up with situation when you'll send secure information over insecure connection.

Comment: Btw this error may occur in case you're using wrong port.