# Show contents of webpage with CURL. Fifa website

Tags: php, curl, html

I am trying to get the contents of this webpage to be shown.

https://sofifa.com/players?aeh=22&ptl=84&pth=99&pn=27&pn=25&pn=23?

But unfortunately, it is not working.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
    function curl_download($Url){// is cURL installed yet?
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
            die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
        }
        // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
        $ch = curl_init("https://sofifa.com/players?aeh=22&ptl=84&pth=99&pn=27&pn=25&pn=23");
        // Now set some options (most are optional)
        // Set URL to download
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ch);
        // User agent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
        // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Timeout in seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        // Download the given URL, and return output
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
?> 
<?php
    include_once('AFIFAtest.php');#this is the file name of the program
    curl_download($url);
?>
```

Comment: This is a tricky thing, because any relative links on the page will break.  For example if the CSS is a relative link it will be broken, because it will look on the site that is doing the showing, instead of the original.  The same goes for Javascript,  `<a>` tags, like navigation links, images etc...  This is why we have `iFrame` tags, well I use them for downloads and uploads,but that's a separate post.

Comment: Instead of going to the website, i want curl to display the webpage only - is this possible in php?

Comment: Define `going to the website`  Your definition of going to it and mine are likely different.  For me going to it is making a HTTP request to the site.  For you it's probably using the browser.  And yes, as I outlined above what happens.  But for me (With my definition) you cant display it without "going" to it.  For you, I would say use an `IFRAME` tag.  However it may be against their TOS policy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)