# Posting to API with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post data to an API with cURL. If I do it via the playground of the API provider it works.

But through my code something doesn't seem to work:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$curl = curl_init('testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/Transaction');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
return $result;

if(curl_error($curl))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}

curl_close($curl);
```

I tried error handling with the `curl_error` function but that doesn't seem to be working either. I never get an error, even if I make some obvious mistakes like purposely changing my API secret to something that doesn't make sense. How do I send the data. How do I post to the API and why am I not getting any errors?

Comment: Your `return` statement stops the execution of your function, so, `curl_error()` is never called. Try to move it under `curl_close()`.

Comment: see if this is not the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: @Syscall i did that now, still no errors even if after i changed my api secret to something that doesnt make sense

Comment: Try `if($result === false)` instead of `if(curl_error($curl))`. Or, what is the output of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: @Syscall var_dump returns nothing hmm. And Still no error even after changing my way to yours.

Comment: `var_dump()` never returns nothing. Add a `die('stop');` after `var_dump`. Also, use `curl_error($curl)` instead of `curl_error($c)`.

Comment: Another thing, what is the value of `$url`? It's redundant with the argument of `curl_init()`.

Comment: @Syscall i did it. The var_dump returns:  string(0) "". The argument in curl_init is the same as the $url variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several notes:

- The `return` statement should be after to check the errors.
- To check errors, you should test `$result === false`.
- The variable `$c` is undefined in `curl_error()`.
- The URL is mal-formed, missing the scheme (eg, `http://`).
- The option `CURLOPT_URL` is redundant, because already defined in `curl_init()`.

Code:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$curl = curl_init('http://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/Transaction');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // already defined in curl_init().
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if($result === false)
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
return $result;
```

Comment: Getting errors now. And the var_dump is no longer emtpy. Much appreciated thank you