# php /Drupal7 Curl Error - SSL read: error

Tags: php, curl, drupal-7

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Return data inplace of echoing on screen
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
    $rsData = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am trying to get data from other(site2) site. Both the website are hosted in same server but different domain.

I have verified the OPenssl is turned on.

> Error Message:SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno
>   104

Comment: Your site is under `https` or `http` ? Usefull function check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Comment: Site is under https

Answer (score 0):

My Firewall has blocked the conection between the hosts in same server, After updating NAT rule it works fine