# PHP telegram bot, sendmessage webhook

Tags: php, bots, telegram, webhooks

I'm writing a telegram robot,
This is my code and I want the user receive the message which they send into the bot:

telegram.php :

```
<?php
 class telegram {

 public $token;

 public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token =  $token; 
}

    public function recievedText()
{
    $text= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    return $text;
} 

public function sendMessage($userid,$text)
{
    $url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$this->token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$userid.'&text='.$text;
    file_get_contents($url)   ;
}
}

?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php

require ('config.php');
require('telegram.php');

$telegram = new telegram(TOKEN);
$result = $telegram->recievedText();
$userid = $result->message->from->id;
$text   = $result->message->text;
$telegram->sendMessage($userid,$text)  ;
?>
```

config.php :

```
<?php

define('TOKEN','----');
?>
```

and I have already set webhook and checked the SSL of my site via [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and it was set,

I don't know where is the problem that when I send the message to the bot it doesn't send back any message!

Answer (score 0):

You checked if you have ssl, but you don't check if you really use it. You also don't check what is the response from the request you do

```
file_get_contents($url)   ;
```

change this line to:

```
$requestResponse = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($http_response_header);
var_dump($requestResponse);
```

to see if you succeed sending the request at first.
Without the response It's just guessing what could go wrong. 
You should see response code = 200 if everything is OK if other number not beginning with 2xx then you fail sending the requrest.

Read about HTTPS connections with [file_get_contents()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/ddg#7499529), or try to use [cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/ddg#4372730). Hint: Just for the debugging you can skip SSL verification so at least this problem at the beginning is eliminated. But remember to turn the verification back on after debugging!

If you do the request as GET query you need to encode the text before putting it at the url - use: [urlencode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for that.

```
$url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$this->token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$userid.'&text='.$text;
```

change to

```
 $url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$this->token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='. urlencode($userid) . '&text='.urlencode($text);
```

or even better make use of [http_build_query()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and encode this way all variable besides `$this->token`. Given link has a plain example so I'll skip giving you code.

Comment: thank you so much your answering. the result is : `array(8) { [0]=> string(24) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" [1]=> string(20) "Server: nginx/1.12.2" [2]=> string(35) "Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 07:42:39 GMT" [3]=> string(30) "Content-Type: application/json" [4]=> string(18) "Content-Length: 80" [5]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [6]=> string(30) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" [7]=> string(81) "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection" } bool(false) ` why the request is failed ? is the problem with ssl of the hosting or anything else ?

Comment: @ZaGol then read the documentation of the telegram API, maybe you need to send JSON header `"Content-Type", "application/json"` and the data as JSON. Unlucky I can't help you more, since I don't know the telegram API

Answer (score 0):

You need to set webhook before anything else. Fire a POST request using Postman to

> https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook
> with Body parameter:

- url: https://your-server/api-endpoint
- drop_pending_updates : true (false) -> (optional) I use this to drop pending messages