# need some information about php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

Please before my question please see those data 1st.

**API URL**: `https://api.awebsite.com/api/redeem`

**Data Sent Method**: **POST**

***Requested Headers:***

```
Host: api.awebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://m.awebsite.com/en/exchange
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 87
Origin: https://m.awebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=e0c4f6ec8a13e963bf6b11ebc33a96d2
TE: Trailers
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Posted Data**

```
{"redeemcode":"f564hfkj4shfee25","gameid":"123456","vcode":"7895","language":"en"}
```

I collect all of those from Browser > Inspect > Network area.

My Question is, Can I use php curl to post data to that api url from my localhost or my server?  I Write my own code but its not working.. Here is my code.

```
//API Url
$url = 'https://api.awebsite.com/api/redeem';

$code = 'f564hfkj4shfee25';
$user = '123456';
$vcode = '7895';

//Initiate cURL.
//$ch = curl_init();
//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'redeemcode' => $code,
    'gameid' => $user,
    'vcode' => $vcode,
    'language' => 'en'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://m.awebsite.com/en/exchange');

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Do you think there is a way to post data using php?

Comment: Can you clarify "not working" a bit? What is in `$result`? Are there errors?

Comment: Might be a problem about SSL. See this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/26641565/3020926

Comment: @Don'tPanic No.. There is no return.. no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send post with cURL to other domain but... the other domain (https://api.awebsite.com/api/redeem) need allow the access with a cross domian policy

```
<?PHP

//API Url
$url = 'https://api.awebsite.com/api/redeem';

$code = 'f564hfkj4shfee25';
$user = '123456';
$vcode = '7895';

//Initiate cURL.
//$ch = curl_init();
//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'redeemcode' => $code,
    'gameid' => $user,
    'vcode' => $vcode,
    'language' => 'en'
);
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

$defaults = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonDataEncoded,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false  //  <= Skip the secure validation 
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, ($defaults));

//Execute the request
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($info);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: its works after add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` .. **Thanks for your code**