# Php curl get amount of bytes written

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

How can i know how much data is written in php curl .
Here is my code which downloads i.e writes the data to my local server from a remote url . But i want to know how much data has been written till now .

```
    <?php
    $url  = 'https://speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin';
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/1gb.bin';

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Don't switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`.  It's a security vulnerability.

Comment: ok i will correct it but solve my problem please @Dharman .

Answer (score 2):

I use this for the downloaded size in bytes (including the size of the file as it is the body of the response) *(after you call `curl_exec($ch);`)*

```
 // $ch is the curl handle
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 echo $info['size_download'];
```

> **CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD** - Total number of bytes downloaded

This is quoted from libcurl [documenation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD.html)

> The amount is only for the latest transfer and will be reset again
>   for each new transfer. This counts actual payload data, what's also
>   commonly called body. All meta and header data are excluded and will
>   not be counted in this number.

And this for the size of the request you made with curl in bytes

```
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 echo $info['request_size'];
```

> **CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE** - Total size of issued requests, currently only for HTTP requests

you can also use the function with the `opt` parameter set to one of the function constants, like

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE);
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
```

[getinfo() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

As you told in comments by Dharman, don't switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`. If you want to use `https` requests check this [php-curl-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)