# How do I ping a webpage in php to make sure it's alive?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of urls for some webpages and I want to make sure that this url ( webpage ) exists and not deleted or it doesn't exist. I want to do it in PHP.

How do I ping a webpage to make sure it's alive?

Comment: Try this SO post, there is a nice example in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php

Comment: Do you want to do this on command or have it as a scheduled task?

Answer (score 3):

```
$urls = array(...);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);

    if ( ! $headers OR strpos($headers[0], '200 OK') === FALSE) {
       // Site is down.
    } 
}
```

Alternatively you could use `ping`.

```
$response = shell_exec('ping ' . escapeshellarg($url));

// Parse $response.
```

#### Update

You mention you want this to be scheduled. Have a look into [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1):

Create a PHP script that fires off an HTTP Request to each URL that you want to be kept-alive.

[PHP HTTP Request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php)

I suggest setting up a Task in your operating system that accesses this script every 15 minutes in order to keep these applications alive. [Here's some info](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) on running PHP from the command line in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?lngWId=8&txtCodeId=1786 for a thorough implementation.