# ping with php phar

Tags: php, ping

i want to use this [script](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-ping.ping.php) to do ping without using the `exec();` or the commands that similar to it.

the problem is i get these errors:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Net_Ping::factory() should not be
>   called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line
>   3
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Net_Ping::_setSystemName() should
>   not be called statically in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\Ping.php on line 141
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Net_Ping::_setPingPath() should
>   not be called statically in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\Ping.php on line 143
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be
>   called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line
>   4

the code on test.php

```
<?php
require_once "Net/Ping.php";
$ping = Net_Ping::factory();
if (PEAR::isError($ping)) {
    echo $ping->getMessage();
} else {
    $ping->setArgs(array('count' => 2));
    var_dump($ping->ping('example.com'));
}
?>
```

Comment: where's your code, it looks like the error messages are clearly explaining what is wrong.

Comment: the code is here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-ping.ping.php and i didn't this file C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\Ping.php i downloaded this from pear.php

Comment: We need the code from `C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://download.networkm.net/code/php/class.ping.1.0.tar.gz) is a ping class I wrote last year when I needed to do this on a system that didn't have PEAR.

Example usage:

```
$ping = new ping();
if (!$ping->setHost('google.com')) exit('Could not set host: '.$this->getLastErrorStr());
var_dump($ping->send());
```

Comment: does it use exec() or similar and if not what yes ?

Comment: No it doesn't exec or similar, it uses the PHP [sockets extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong, the PEAR component is just not fit for E_STRICT. The code you have is okay, but the PEAR code doesn't say the method is static, so PHP will emit an E_STRICT warning. That's not something you can really change, but you *can* opt to ignore it, by adjusting your error_reporting settings.

```
<?php
// before PEAR stuff.
$errLevel = error_reporting( E_ALL );

// PEAR stuff.
require_once "Net/Ping.php";
$ping = Net_Ping::factory();
if (PEAR::isError($ping)) {
    echo $ping->getMessage();
} else {
    $ping->setArgs(array('count' => 2));
    $result = $ping->ping('example.com');
}

// restore the original error level.
error_reporting( $errLevel );
var_dump( $result );
```