# Ping / Post Form

Tags: php, curl, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ping site and return result in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php)

How do you ping a host/server with PHP to retrieve a (true / false) response. I was reading how to do it with pear Net_ping but I was wondering if there is a curl way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Pinging uses the ICMP Protocol.

There's no inbuilt functionality to use that protocol.

You can create raw sockets with PHP to do the transmission manually - but raw socket creating will require root access.

[Here's](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?lngWId=8&txtCodeId=1786) how to do so.

You can also exec the ping utility. ([Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=37370) for a discussion).

Alternatively you could just see if the server emits a response using another protocol, like HTTP.