# Going about programming a minecraft server status checking program

Tags: php, python, sql-server, minecraft

I'm wanting to make a program which allows for me to check the status of Minecraft servers whether they're online, offline or full. How would I go about doing so? I'm thinking PHP server side, Python client side and SQL as server?

I need some major advice on what needs to be done to achieve such a task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a database. Ping the server. If it responds, it's up...display a large green checkmark. If it doesn't respond...it's down. Display a large red x. You can do that in the FB API or in plain PHP anywhere.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php), which provides the following code:

```
function ping($host, $port, $timeout)
{ 
  $tB = microtime(true); 
  $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
  if (!$fP) { return "down"; } 
  $tA = microtime(true); 
  return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms"; 
}
```

Comment: David, such helpful and straight to the point advice. Thanks buddy. Also, I mentioned SQL by accident. It'll be for another part of this program but I didn't need help with that part so i'm not sure why I even mentioned it lol.

Answer (score 1):

Notably if you want more information than just the server up/down status you can use the MineQuery protocol that most servers have enabled.

More info @ [DinnerBone's tool](http://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/status/).

This will allow you to get the current/max players, MOTD, game version, and some other details if the server uses CraftBukkit.

Also [this version written in PHP](https://github.com/vexsoftware/minequery-php/blob/master/minequery.class.php).