# How to check a url exist or not in php

Tags: php, url, file-exists

I want to check the url 
`http://example.com/file.txt`
 exist or not in php. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(! @ file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/file.txt')){
  echo 'path doesn't exist';
}
```

This is the easiest way to do it.  If you are unfamiliar with the `@`, that will instruct the function to return false if it would have otherwise thrown an error

Comment: OT: is there any general consensus over whether `@!` or `!@` is preferred? I use the former, and feel weird around the latter for some reason--maybe the `@` *after* an operator feels like it shouldn't work, even though it obviously should.

Comment: Fix the syntax error. and check the correct type of return. if(@file_get_contents('http://localhost/mh/t.php')===false){ echo 'path doesnt exist'; }

Comment: Be sure you enable file_get_contents for other domains. That is done in php.ini.

Comment: @habeebperwad if you use an `@` and it fails, it will return `0`, not `false` - you can testing it with `if` as it is falsey, or `===0` but not `===false`.

Comment: "PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.". @ won't return any value, Right? The above code will failif the url returns a file with no content.

Answer (score 3):

The would use the PHP curl extension:

```
$ch = curl_init();                                  // set up curl
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );              // the url to request
if ( false===( $response = curl_exec( $ch ) ) ){    // fetch remote contents
    $error = curl_error( $ch );                  
    // doesn't exist
}
curl_close( $ch );                                  // close the resource
```

Comment: Yep. If file_exists doesn't work, this is the most canonically correct solution, though Landon's would also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename="http://example.com/file.txt";    

if (file_exists($filename)) {
   echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
   echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

OR

```
if (fopen($filename, "r"))
{
   echo "File Exists"; 
}
else
{
   echo "Can't Connect to File";
}
```

Comment: @habeebperwad try the second option in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this function on [Ping site and return result in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239068/ping-site-and-return-result-in-php).

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
    {  
        if($url == NULL) return false;  
        $ch = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
        $data = curl_exec($ch);  
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
        curl_close($ch);  
        if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
            return true;  
        } else {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with the response, I got success by doing this

```
$url = "http://example.com/file.txt";       
if(! @(file_get_contents($url))){
    return false;
}
$content = file_get_contents($url);
return $content;
```

You can follow the code to check the file exist at location or not.