# How to check website is online if it is password protected

Tags: php, .htaccess, ping, password-protection

I just want to write a php code to check if password protected website is online or offline. I know the code to check whether if website is online or offline but it is not working if the website is password protected through .htaccess. llike if you open then website then an alert box comes and ask about the user name and password.
If i use this code then it is just saying that the website is offline because it cannot by pass the user name and password.

```
$host = 'http://gforms.orbnexus.com';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
echo 'online!';
fclose($socket);
} else {
echo 'offline.';
}
```

Can any one please help me? Is there any way to by-pass user name and password?

Comment: Use cURL instead, here's a good function for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239090/1765851

Comment: Hi, I used this function but it is still saying fail. Please check if i am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: if(urlExists("http://gforms.orbnexus.com") == true){echo success';}else {echo 'fail';}
function urlExists($url)  {  
        if($url == NULL) return false;  
        $ch = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
        $data = curl_exec($ch);  
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
        curl_close($ch);   
        if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){ return true;  
        } else {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }

Comment: What about logging in with your script?

Comment: How would I do it? this alert login box is coming from htaccess. How can i pass the user name and password?

Comment: actually I never used a htaccess login. But probably this could help you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fact that it asks for a username and password means its online. I'm also sure you can make sure when you send your request that you get back a header, if nothing comes back the website is down.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference page](http://frankkoehl.com/2009/09/http-status-code-curl-php/)

Use cURL to get your target, then check the http status code.  If you get a 401 then it there's an authentication issue