# switch from curl to multi_curl or speed up url validator

Tags: php, curl

i have a database with reciprocal urls and check it daily for availability, so i can sort available links with unavailable.

i do it in such way:

```
<?php

foreach($urls as $url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 60000);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:107');

  $page = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($ch);  

  if($httpcode>=100 && $httpcode<600) echo $httpcode; else echo '0';
}

?>
```

It output the header code. How can i use same function in more sleep way? because in this way to execute this script take about 15 minutes for 100 links. Thank you for any ideas and suggestions. I also tried to use multi_curl, but cant understand how to manage outputs.

Comment: would pinging the url be faster? (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239082/402585)

Comment: no, ping is not available, any other methods?

Comment: by not available do you mean you don't have fSockOpen() or you need the content of the web page?

Comment: there is no direct ipaddres because all links are over same proxy

Comment: ... you can ping a url (look at the link in the 1st comment)

Comment: echo ping("www.google.com", 80, 10);?   it lookup to ipaddress, its not available :(

Comment: Ahh, sorry then, no idea.

Comment: i will try to to install fsockopen and try it. But maybe there is an alternative way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74419/discussion-between-eugenia-and-edd-turtle).